How will a normal shock forming on a wing create drag?
When you're going close to supersonic speeds, the air over the wing is actually getting accelerated to supersonic. When the pressure recovery area comes, this accelerated air turns into a shock because it has to decelerate rapidly.
The thing is, all this normal shock is doing is decelerating the flow over the wing.
It would make sense if there was a normal shock on the front of an airfoil causing drag, because that would be pushing in the opposite direction of flight. However, the shock I'm talking about is on the rear section of the wing, and it travels towards the trailing edge as you speed up.
I don't really see how this normal shock could cause a drag increase knowing all it does it decelerate the flow, so how does this work?

(The only way I see this normal shock making drag is if it caused separation)

Your comment is largely correct -- the shock on the wing will almost always cause separation, which is a large source of drag.
This is the predominant cause of drag during the transonic drag rise.  It is often called 'wave drag', but that is erroneous.
